# Is there any solution to this Diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation $a^n+n=b^2$, where $(a,n)>2$ are positive integers. Is it true that there exist no integer solutions $b$ of this equation? Can one find a counterexample?

I am unable to do either.

Comment: What makes you sure that this is known ? For $3\le a,n \le 3\ 000$ , there is no solution, but I have also no idea to prove that there is none. I am curious whether someone can prove it and , if yes, how.

Comment: If we generalize the equation to $a^n+n=b^c$ then we have a solution which is $5^3+3=2^7$ but, for the equation $a^n+n=b^2$ I'm uncertain & also unable to prove that there are none.

Comment: It's easy to see any solution must have $n$ odd, because if $n$ is even, $(a^{n/2})^2<b^2<(a^{n/2}+1)^2$

Comment: Does this mean that we should only try for $n$ to be any odd prime or any positive odd integer ignoring the positive even integers?

Comment: Any odd positive integer, not just primes.

Answer (score 1):

The Diophantine equation
$$
y^n=f(x)
$$
for an irreducible polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients of degree $m\ge 2$ has only finitely many solutions, provided $(m,n)\neq (2,2)$. This is due to Carl Ludwig Siegel. The following reference discusses the special case $f(x)=x^2+c$, which might be interesting.

Reference: see [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/RCM/Articulos/793.pdf).

Comment: The choices in the diophantine equation of the referral are vast for $c$ but, in this equation, it's having little choice i.e. the exponent $n$ is $c$ & including the sign issue.

Answer (score 0):

**This is also an extended comment**

There are some bounds on sum of logs like Baker/[Rhin](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Georges_Rhin/publication/282190026_Approximants_de_Pade_et_mesures_effectives_d%27irrationalite/links/582b257d08ae004f74afa09e/Approximants-de-Pade-et-mesures-effectives-dirrationalite.pdf) studied, but I don't know if it can be generalized.

This would go like this:

$$\frac{b^2}{a^n}-1>\log(\frac{b^2}{a^n})=|2\cdot\log(b)-n\cdot\log(a)|$$

Using the bound $|µ_1\log (b)+µ_2\log (a)|\geq H^{-c}$ with $H=max(|µ_1|,|µ_2|)$) we would have

$$|2\cdot\log(b)-n\cdot\log(a)|>\frac 1{n^{c}}$$
$$\frac{b^2-a^n}{a^n}>\frac 1{n^{c}}$$
$$n=b^2-a^n>\frac {a^n}{n^{c}}$$
$$n^{c+1}>a^n$$

Knowing that $a>2$ and $c$ can be relatively small, the size of $n$ in the last inequality must also be very limited.